# How to understand two "to know"s in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> One wild cart ride later they stood blinking in the sunlight outside Gringotts. Harry didn't know where to run first now that he had a bag full of money. He didn't have **to know** how many Galleons there were to a pound **to know** that he was holding more money than he'd had in his whole life -- more money than even Dudley had ever had.

I don't know how to parse the sentence correctly. The first "**to know**" is easy for me to understand. The second "**to know**" got me lost. Can someone help to identify what the second "**to know**" does there?

P.S. The passage is from the book Harry Potter.

Comment: You don't have to know the theory of thermodynamics to know that you will get burned if you put your hand on the stove.   You don't have to cuss to get your point across. You have to be tall to play professional basketball.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second instance of '*to know*' here is equivalent to '***in order*** to know'. So it can be simplified like this:

> There was no need for him *to know* some number *in order to know/understand* that he
>   had a lot of money.